# Problem with Dependency Property

Tags: silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties

I am using a [websites](http://tozon.info/blog/post/2009/03/16/Dynamic-Data-Forms-for-Silverlight-with-a-Data-Template-Selector-Control.aspx) code for reference, but what I am trying to do is not working. The backing property never changes...I dont know if what I am expecting to happen is wrong..

```
public class QuestionTemplateSelector : UserControl
    {
        public DataTemplate TemplateString { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateBoolean { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateSingleMultipleChoice { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateAnyMultipleChoice { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="QuestionType" /> dependency property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string QuestionTypePropertyName = "QuestionType";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="QuestionType" />
        /// property. This is a dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public string QuestionType
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(QuestionTypeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(QuestionTypeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="QuestionType" /> dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            QuestionTypePropertyName,
            typeof(string),
            typeof(QuestionTemplateSelector), new PropertyMetadata(QuestionTypeChangedCallBack));

        private static void QuestionTypeChangedCallBack(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Old Value: {1}{0}New Value: {2}", " - ", e.OldValue, e.NewValue));

        }

        public QuestionTemplateSelector():base()
        {
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);

        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string questiontype = QuestionType;
            Debug.WriteLine(sender);


            if (questiontype == "Boolean")
            {
                Content = TemplateBoolean.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Free Text")
            {
                Content = TemplateString.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Single Multiple Choice")
            {
                Content = TemplateSingleMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Any Multiple Choice")
            {
                Content = TemplateAnyMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else
            {
                Content = null;
            }
        }//onLoaded

    }//QuestionTemplateSelector
```

I have a feeling it has to do with the onloaded. Where I really need code is in the Callback, but because its static I cant get access to the instance methods I need. How should I proceed? I can post more code if you need.

```
        public QuestionTemplateSelector():base()
        {
            Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);

        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            string questiontype = QuestionType;
            Debug.WriteLine(sender);


            if (questiontype == "Boolean")
            {
                Content = TemplateBoolean.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Free Text")
            {
                Content = TemplateString.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Single Multiple Choice")
            {
                Content = TemplateSingleMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == "Any Multiple Choice")
            {
                Content = TemplateAnyMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else
            {
                Content = null;
            }
        }//onLoaded
```

I can verify that the code is actually changing in the callback, but the CLR property seems to never be updated.

Comment: You haven't posted the actual property's declaration. What does that look like?

Comment: @Gabe...sorry bout that, it was an oversite on my part. I have the full code for the control in there now...

Comment: So let me get it straight! The Callback is called, but in the Loaded eventHandler the QuestionType (clr) property returns null?

Comment: yep..thats the way its acting

Comment: when i am debugging the onloaded hits first then the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it working. But I am not sure this is absolutely correct.

```
public class QuestionTemplateSelector : UserControl
    {
        public DataTemplate TemplateString { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateBoolean { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateSingleMultipleChoice { get; set; }
        public DataTemplate TemplateAnyMultipleChoice { get; set; }


        /// <summary>
        /// The <see cref="QuestionType" /> dependency property's name.
        /// </summary>
        public const string QuestionTypePropertyName = "QuestionType";

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the value of the <see cref="QuestionType" />
        /// property. This is a dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public Int64 QuestionType
        {
            get
            {
                return (Int64)GetValue(QuestionTypeProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(QuestionTypeProperty, value);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Identifies the <see cref="QuestionType" /> dependency property.
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty QuestionTypeProperty;

        private static void QuestionTypeChangedCallBack(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {

            ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).QuestionType = (Int64)e.NewValue;
            OnLoaded(obj, (Int64)e.NewValue);

        }



        static QuestionTemplateSelector()
        {
            QuestionTypeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
           "QuestionType",
           typeof(Int64),
           typeof(QuestionTemplateSelector), new PropertyMetadata(QuestionTypeChangedCallBack));

            //Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(OnLoaded);

        }

        private static void OnLoaded(DependencyObject obj, Int64 e)
        {

            Int64 questiontype = e;
            if (questiontype == 1)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Boolean");
                ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).Content = ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).TemplateBoolean.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == 2)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("FreeText");
                ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).Content = ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).TemplateString.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == 3)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Single Multiple Choice");
                ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).Content = ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).TemplateSingleMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else if (questiontype == 4)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Any Multiple Choice");
                ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).Content = ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).TemplateAnyMultipleChoice.LoadContent() as UIElement;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("NONE");
                ((QuestionTemplateSelector)obj).Content = null;
            }
        }//onLoaded



    }//QuestionTemplateSelector
```